# xUnit test Spring web application end-to-end

Tags: spring, testing, web-applications, junit

What's the best way to approach the following (integration/unit) test scenario for a Spring JSP web app:

- run with JUnitRunner
- access to Spring context (@Inject beans into the test)
- send requests to a lightweight web server started from inside the test that renders the entire html including JSP
- auto rollback transactions
- no browser (Selenium is out)
- real running servlet container (no MockServlet) to test JSP (spring-text-mvc is out)

Goals:

- run with maven build cycle
- isolated test - each test can set all beans into the desired state
- check html output for JSP pages
- check bean status / database status

Is there a framework for this? Can I combine frameworks? Maybe I need to setup my own server and start it and then run actual requests against localhost.. But then how can I influence the server's context and run rollbacks against it?

Thanks for pointers, links and thoughts.

---

**edit**

I just read about using an embedded jetty to test a spring app. Not sure if that's the right way to go. I think the problem will be that the deployed app and my test don't have the same context. Will investigate further, any thoughts on this are welcome.

---

**edit2**

Found another project that sounds promising: [JWebUnit](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/12/embedded-integration-testing-of-web-applications.html#conclusion-and-unfinished-business). Will try this out and update with feedback. Would love to hear about any experience with using that framework to solve problems similar to mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted this question in more detail at a google group for test driven design. Quite an interesting discussion for anyone struggling to test automate or test drive their web application:
[Growing Object Oriented Software - Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/growing-object-oriented-software/siUu67betIs)

Answer (score 1):

I have not used this yet, but this is very promising for Spring-MVC tests - https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-test-mvc . It satisfies 1(run with JUnitRunner), 2(access to Spring Context), 4(transaction rollback support), 5 (no Browser). On 3, there is no need to start a lightweight webserver, it can programmatically hook up the entire Spring MVC infrastructure and test it end to end.

Comment: Yeah, we started with spring-test-mvc.. but it has no servlet context so it won't render JSP.. I'll update my post

Comment: Yes, it won't render jsp, since this is done by the container - here is another question along these lines that I had just answered - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11050856/204788 , you can only validate that the path to final jsp is what you expect it to be, not the rendered content itself.

Comment: Hehe, you answered my original question.. That's why I wanted to run tests against a real server but one that I can influence directly from the test..

Answer (score 0):

this blog post could be a good start http://www.scarba05.co.uk/blog/2010/07/more-on-integration-testing-of-spring%E2%80%99s-mvc-annotation-mapppings-for-controllers/

Comment: Thank's for the pointer. I updated my post to clearify.. We cannot use a mock servlet, we need a real servlet, otherwise JSP pages wont get rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Since the retirement of Jakarta Cactus which was an in-container based testing framework, [Arquillian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html) is the most active project. Check their latest Spring extension [here](http://planet.jboss.org/post/arquillian_spring_framework_extension_1_0_0_alpha1_released). It supports a number of containers. Here is the [list](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Container+adapters)