# Response data missing in Spring MVC test

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I have a controller that writes to the `ModelMap` like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dataset")
public class DatasetController {

    @Autowired
    DatasetDao datasetDao;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getDataset(@RequestParam String name, ModelMap model) {
        Dataset ds = datasetDao.get(name);
        model.addAttribute("response", new DatasetResponse(ds));
        return "Success";
    }
```

I want to write a test case that gets a dataset and then performs more actions based on its contents. But, I'm having trouble getting data out of the service. My test case so far is:

```
@Test
public void testProducesXml() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/dataset.xml").param("name", "foo"))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(model().attribute("Response",
            hasProperty("name", is("foo"))))
        .andExpect(xpath("/dataset/name").string("foo"));
}
```

The `model().attribute` line passes, but the test fails at `xpath` with:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.

Ultimately I'd like to get a copy of the `DatasetResponse` in my test function so I can do other things with it. I tried using `andReturn()`, but that fails for the same reason that `xpath` fails.

It turns out that even though there's a `DatasetResponse` in the model, the body of the response is empty:

```
ModelAndView:
    View name = Success
         View = null
    Attribute = Response
        value = org.vpac.web.model.response.DatasetResponse@457fdd58
       errors = []

MockHttpServletResponse:
       Status = 200
Error message = null
      Headers = {}
 Content type = null
         Body =
```

However if I start the app in Tomcat and go to `/dataset.xml?name=foo` in my browser, I can see the data as XML.

So, why is the body empty, and how can I get a reference to the `DatasetResponse`? **Edit** Do I need to trigger the view to render the model, or something?

Comment: It is in the scope of http request object that is there in attributes as I can see. Attribute are not part of body of the response. Response will be created by "dataset/create" view. Please check what this view is returning to the client back.

Comment: show the xml you trying to pass.the error is when trying to pass the xml.just because it is opened in the browser doesnt mean that its a valid xml . it will interpret anything.

Comment: How does your setup look like? `getDataset` doesn't return data but the name of a view. You need a full integration test to get the actual response.

Comment: @Braj OK you got me, the controller actually returns "Success". I admit I'm taking over this code from someone else and I don't really know how it's supposed to work. AFAIK there is no "Success" view, but in my `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` there are `defaultViews` configured, one of which is an `xml.MarshallingView` with a `Jaxb2Marshaller`, which points to a package full of `javax.xml`-annotated beans such as `DatasetResponse`.

Comment: @Pri you're right, there's no XML declaration shown in the browser. But from the exception I'm pretty sure the document in the test is literally empty (see also the `Body = ` in the printout). @zero, so how do I set up a full integration test? If I change my controller to use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`, and return a `DatasetResponse` instead of a `String`, then the body of the response contains the right document and the `xpath` tests work. But the ModelAndView is empty, and the `andExpect(model()` lines fail.

Comment: Hmm, I guess this is a possible duplicate of [Spring-Test-MVC / MockServletContext - content empty in test but working on Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046710/spring-test-mvc-mockservletcontext-content-empty-in-test-but-working-on-tomc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This came down to the test being misconfigured: my MVC config is split across two files, as specified in my `web.xml` file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml 
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

But following examples from elsewhere, I only had my test class annotated with:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml")
@Transactional
public class DatasetTest {
    ...
```

Adding the missing `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` fixes the problem:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({
    "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml",
    "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml"})
@Transactional
public class DatasetTest {
    ...
```

Now the ModelAndView contain the objects that I return from the controller, and the body of the response is not empty. `.andExpect(xpath` works as expected, and I can get a copy of the response object with:

```
mockMvc.perform(...).andReturn().getModelAndView().getModel().get("Response");
```